# Dit-on plutôt « Bonjour, je vous appelle pour (vous) signaler la perte de/ pour (vous) signaler que j’ai perdu ma carte de crédit » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation

1. Bonjour, je vous appelle pour signaler la perte de ma carte de crédit. (Sans vous précédant le verbe « signaler ».
2. Bonjour, je vous appelle pour vous signaler la perte de ma carte de crédit. (Avec vous précédant le verbe « signaler »).
3. Bonjour, je vous appelle pour signaler que j’ai perdu ma carte de crédit. (Sans vous précédant le verbe « signaler ».
4. Bonjour, je vous appelle pour vous signaler que j’ai perdu ma carte de crédit. (Avec vous précédant le verbe « signaler »).
   Merci.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait de différence d'usage entre « signaler la perte » et « signaler que j'ai perdu », sauf si c'est quelqu'un d'autre qui a perdu cette carte.

Sinon, j'éviterais la répétition des *vous* dans « je **vous** appelle pour **vous** » mais on l'entend quand même couramment.

On peut éviter cette répétition aussi avec:

> Bonjour, j'appelle pour vous signaler...

Il existe une « infinité » de variantes:

> Bonjour, j'appelle pour vous informer de la perte...
> Bonjour, j'appelle parce que j'ai perdu...
> Bonjour, j'ai perdu ma carte de crédit...
> Bonjour, c'est pour signaler la perte de ma carte de crédit...